# org-table - managing my badge times

Tags: elisp

I have the following `org-table`

| datum | werk start | pauze start | pauze stop | werk stop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/02/2024 | 09:48 | 12:45 | 13:14 | 17:22 |
| 13/02/2024 | 08:01 | 12:06 | 12:31 | 16:38 |
| 14/02/2024 | 07:38 | 12:12 | 12:38 | 16:48 |
| 15/02/2024 | 08:11 | 13:11 | 13:28 | 17:08 |

Now I want to calculate how many hours I did per day and see if I did too much or too little in a month.

For this I wrote some helper functions.

```lisp
   (defun hm-to-minutes (str)
     (let* ((lst (split-string str ":"))
            (hour (car lst))
            (minute (cadr lst)))
       (+ (* (string-to-number hour) 60)
          (string-to-number minute))))

   (defun hm-get-minutes (str)
     (string-to-number (cadr (split-string str ":"))))

   (defun minutes-to-hm (minutes)
     (concat (format "%02d"  (/ minutes 60))
             ":"
             (format "%02d" (% minutes 60))))

  (defun hm-minutes-floor-quarter (str)
    (let* ((original (hm-to-minutes str))
          (minutes (hm-get-minutes str))
          (remainder (% minutes 15)))
      (- original remainder)))

   (defun hm-floor-quarter (str)
     (minutes-to-hm (hm-minutes-floor-quarter str)))

   (defun hm-ceil-quarter (str)
     (minutes-to-hm (+ (hm-minutes-floor-quarter str) 15)))
```

I also wrote some table functions, however I'm not happy with all the intermediate columns and the result on the last row in the columns I don't need.

| datum | werk start | pauze start | pauze stop | werk stop | werkelijk start | werkelijk stop | pauze | te doen | gepresteerd | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/02/2024 | 09:48 | 12:45 | 13:14 | 17:22 | 10:00 | 17:15 | 00:30 | 08:00 | 06:45 | -01:15 |
| 13/02/2024 | 08:01 | 12:06 | 12:31 | 16:38 | 08:15 | 16:30 | 00:30 | 08:00 | 07:45 | -00:15 |
| 14/02/2024 | 07:38 | 12:12 | 12:38 | 16:48 | 07:45 | 16:45 | 00:30 | 08:00 | 08:30 | 00:30 |
| 15/02/2024 | 08:11 | 13:11 | 13:28 | 17:08 | 08:15 | 17:00 | 00:30 | 08:00 | 08:15 | 00:15 |
|  |  |  |  |  | #ERROR | #ERROR | 00:15 | 08:00 | -00:15 | -00:45 |

```
#+TBLFM: $6='(hm-ceil-quarter $2)
#+TBLFM: $7='(hm-floor-quarter $5)
#+TBLFM: $8=$4 - $3;U
#+TBLFM: $8='(hm-ceil-quarter $8)
#+TBLFM: $9=08:00;U
#+TBLFM: $10=($7 - $6 - $8);U
#+TBLFM: $11=($10 - $9);U::@>$11=vsum(@2..@-1);U
```

I'm most interested in columns `gepresteerd` and `delta`.